# Change what user writes anywhere on the screen to another string

Tags: arch-linux, x11, keyboard, dwm, keyboard-event

So I'd like to understand this problem that I'm trying to solve and see if it's even possible to do it, realistically. I want to write a script, or something like that, that would change some string that I write anywhere (terminal, browser, etc.) to another string.

For example, if I write "tdx" into the web browser's search bar I'd like it to then show up as "Rust Documentation", or if I write "ffx" into the terminal it'd show up as "firefox".

I know about bash aliases, that's not what I'm looking for. I'm specifically interested in the text changing right there on the screen. And as I said, I'd like to capture, and change it anywhere on the screen.

I don't even really know how to search for such a thing on the web, so some pointers on that'd be nice too. At this moment I'm completely stuck at step 0.

Details:

- OS: Arch Linux
- Window Manager: DWM

I use X11.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like `hotstrings` in AutoHotkey?

Comment: Your comment gave me the hint that was needed. I found this https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki and it seems promising. Investigating at the moment

Answer (score 2):

I agree that AutoKey is perfect for what you were looking for. Also, for future searches of that kind, "text expander" is what you'd want to use in searches.

Answer (score 1):

So, https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki was the answer to my question, thanks to @Panki, for helping me get on track! Autokey expands your abbreviations like "tdx" into anything anywhere where you type it. Magnificent!